# Android TextView Background

Tags: android, textview

i have a design which demands a background like the image below for the number on the right hand side. Is there any we can achieve this in Android ?

[image]

Will i need to make a 9 patch image and set it as a background ?

Comment: If your texts are not gonna fixed width, surely you need to use 9patch...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First, create a shape to have rounded corners.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="5px"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" /> 
</shape>
```

Then apply this as the background to your Views:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="blah blah blah blah"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You may need to do some tweaking. You may even be able to discard the `LinearLayout` and set the `android:background` of the `TextView` to `@drawable/rounded_edges`

Comment: thank you i will try it right away and get back to you. if assign it to the textview. will i need to give the padding ?

Comment: Depends. If your text is getting cut by the corners, you should give some padding.

Comment: `android:radius="5px"`. Why not `5dp`?

Answer (score 4):

First create a drawable resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_textview.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
 <solid android:color="#cccccc"/>
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then reference this drawable in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_textview" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**One of the good Reference :**

[TextView with rounded corners](http://jeviss.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/textview-with-rounded-corners/)

Thanks.

Comment: @Harsha M V see my edit I have added one good reference link too.

Comment: is it a good practice to add padding in text view or in the shape ?

Comment: @HarshaMV yes in most of the case. As shape take effect on textview space so it might possible your text gets cut off there. That is the only reason of giving padding.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but for anyone who struggles with this, I strongly recommend [ViewBadger library](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)