# I would like to know how to make my Text Fields look differently then the default in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I would like to know how to make my Text Fields look differently then the default in android eclipse.I mean giving it borders or making it more puffy almost like a button. Your answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can create a picture with your desired look and set it as a background for the textview

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: Assign them a 9 patch or a custom drawable. Even better, you might use a selector, to represent different states (i.e.: focused, pressed, disabled, normal)

Answer (score 1):

you have to custom the drawable(`edit_text.xml`) :

In the drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_window_focused="false"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />

<item
    android:state_window_focused="false"
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />

<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_pressed" />

<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_selected" />

<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />

<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_selected" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />
```

Then in ur layout use this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/edit1_text"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/edit2_text"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must use `xml drawables` and then set them as the `background` of your view.

this might help
[Android TextView Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303072/android-textview-background)

Answer (score 0):

Use this one it will help you.

```
<LinaerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/editbox_bg" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/editbox_bg"  />

</LinaerLayout>
```

editbox_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />

        <corners android:radius="4dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/edittext_text" />   
    </shape>
```

For this you have to use custome shape for edittext background..